# Problem getting a Javascript dynamic Object property value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am running a React Material-UI autocomplete component and am struggling with reading a Javascript Object property within a handleSelect function.

I can get the townname value, although this is not the React-way:

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById('combo-box-demo').value;
```

I am having a problem trying to get the corresponding townid property value of a Javascript Object.

I feel that I have tried all the obvious things such as Object.property and Object["property"], but none will compile ... they all give the TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

However, I can see the data in the Google Chrome console window.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Many thanks in advance.

My code:

```
[/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import axios from 'axios';   // Asynchronous communication with Server

export default function Autocomplete_ComboBoxDemo(props) {

  var url_orig = props.data.url;

  const loading = true;
  const \[responseData, setResponseData\] = React.useState(\[\]);

  var data = \[\];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;
 
    if (!loading) {
      return undefined;
    }  // if
  })  // React.useEffect()

  const handleChange = (event) => {

    // Replace <event.target.value>
    var url = url_orig.replace("<event.target.value>", event.target.value)

    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {

      data = response.data.data\[props.data.userSelectedValue\];  // OK

      setResponseData(data)
      })  // .then((response)
  }

  const handleSelect = (event) => {
    console.log("Entered handleSelect")

    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('combo-box-demo').value;

    console.log("selectedValue=", selectedValue)

    console.log("responseData=", responseData)

    var dataIndex = responseData.findIndex(x => x.townname === selectedValue);
    console.log("dataIndex=", dataIndex)
   
    var selectedID = responseData\[dataIndex\];

    console.log("selectedID=", selectedID)
    console.log("typeof(selectedID)=", typeof(selectedID))

    console.log("responseData\[dataIndex\]=", responseData\[dataIndex\])
  }

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"

      options={responseData}

      getOptionLabel={(responseData) => responseData\[props.data.userSelectedValue\]}

      style={{ width: 300 }}

      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={props.data.TextFieldlabel} onChange={handleChange} onSelect={handleSelect}/>

      }
    />
  );
}][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onChange prop and set one method in it you will get the value in val parameter

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"

  options={responseData}
  onChange={(e, val) => updateValue(e, val)}
  getOptionLabel={(responseData) => responseData\[props.data.userSelectedValue\]}

  style={{ width: 300 }}

  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={props.data.TextFieldlabel} onChange={handleChange} onSelect={handleSelect}/>

  }
/>
```

declare one method

```
const updateValue=(e, val)=>{
  console.log(e.taget.value);
  console.log(val);
}
```

in the first console result, you get a label and in the second one you get your desired result